# Memory utilization per database - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the memory utilization per database(using dmvs) in a sql server instance,
ie (Buffer Cache + Procedure Cache) over a period of time. 
 I have the query to get the buffer cache utilization, what i require is procedure cache, plus any other parameter that a database will use in terms of memory.

```
-- Get total buffer usage by database for current instance

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name],
COUNT(*) * 8/1024.0 AS [Cached Size (MB)]
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
WHERE database_id > 4 -- system databases
AND database_id <> 32767 -- ResourceDB
GROUP BY DB_NAME(database_id)    
ORDER BY [Cached Size (MB)] DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Also if this can be compared with some perfmon counter info, it would be great

Comment: Depends on your server configuration. Too localised + not a real question.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear - I meant how can it be found out programatically, using dmvs.. thank you

Comment: Why would you add the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to this query??

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT db = DB_NAME(t.dbid), plan_cache_kb = SUM(size_in_bytes/1024) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE t.dbid < 32767
GROUP BY t.dbid
ORDER BY plan_cache_kb DESC;
```

[This tip I wrote on mssqltips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2393/determine-sql-server-memory-use-by-database-and-object/) might be useful as well if you want to dig deeper into buffer usage.